# Subscript out of bounds error in R package ODEsensitivity

Tags: r, ode

I've developed a pharmacokinetic / pharmacodynamic ODE model and I want to use ODEsensitivity to get the Sobol sensitivities for my rate constants. I originally made my model in dMod, but I extracted the equations so I can run ODEsobol(). I've reformatted my model as shown in code below, which parallels the examples in the documentation.

```
library(dMod)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(ODEsensitivity)

myODEmod <- function(Time, State, Pars) {
  with(as.list(c(State, Pars)), {
    dabgbxster_B <- -1*(k01*abgbxster_B*rcep_B) +1*(k02*abgbxsterxrcep_B) +1*(k03*abgb_B*ster_B) -1*(k04*abgbxster_B) -1*(k06*abgbxster_B)
    drcep_B <- -1*(k01*abgbxster_B*rcep_B) +1*(k02*abgbxsterxrcep_B) -1*(k01*abgb_B*rcep_B) +1*(k02*abgbxrcep_B) +1*(k35*abgbxrcep_B) +1*(k55*rcep_C1)*(0.012/18)
    dabgbxsterxrcep_B <- 1*(k01*abgbxster_B*rcep_B) -1*(k02*abgbxsterxrcep_B) +1*(k03*abgbxrcep_B*ster_B) -1*(k04*abgbxsterxrcep_B) -1*(k45*abgbxsterxrcep_B)
    dabgb_B <- -1*(k01*abgb_B*rcep_B) +1*(k02*abgbxrcep_B) -1*(k03*abgb_B*ster_B) +1*(k04*abgbxster_B) -1*(k06*abgb_B)
    dabgbxrcep_B <- 1*(k01*abgb_B*rcep_B) -1*(k02*abgbxrcep_B) -1*(k03*abgbxrcep_B*ster_B) +1*(k04*abgbxsterxrcep_B) -1*(k35*abgbxrcep_B)
    dster_B <- -1*(k03*abgb_B*ster_B) +1*(k04*abgbxster_B) -1*(k03*abgbxrcep_B*ster_B) +1*(k04*abgbxsterxrcep_B) +1*(k06*abgbxster_B) -1*(k07*ster_B) -1*(k08*ster_B) +1*(k28*ster_C1)*(0.012/18) -1*(k38*ster_B) +1*(k48*ster_C2)*(24/18)
    dster_C1 <- 1*(k08*ster_B)*(18/0.012) -1*(k28*ster_C1) +1*(k45*abgbxsterxrcep_B)*(18/0.012)
    dster_C2 <- 1*(k38*ster_B)*(18/24) -1*(k48*ster_C2)
    drcep_C1 <- 1*(k45*abgbxsterxrcep_B)*(18/0.012) -1*(k55*rcep_C1)
    return(list( c(dabgbxster_B, drcep_B, dabgbxsterxrcep_B, dabgb_B, dabgbxrcep_B, dster_B, dster_C1, dster_C2, drcep_C1) ))
  })
}

parnames = c("abgbxster_B", "rcep_B", "abgbxsterxrcep_B", "abgb_B", "abgbxrcep_B", "ster_B", 
             "ster_C1", "ster_C2", "rcep_C1", "k01", "k02", "k03", "k04", "k06", "k35", 
             "k55", "k45", "k07", "k08", "k28", "k38", "k48")
mypars = c(1e-10, 4.78e-10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1e+06, 3.86e-04, 3.98e+04, 2.20e-05, 2.01e-06, 
           1.90e-03, 1.80e+11, 2.28e-05, 3.08e-05, 6.804e-08, 1.0206e-04, 2.4048e-03, 1.731456e-04)
names(mypars) = parnames
mylower <- mypars/100
myupper <- mypars*100
myinit <- mypars[ c("abgbxster_B", "rcep_B", "abgbxsterxrcep_B", "abgb_B", 
                    "abgbxrcep_B", "ster_B", "ster_C1", "ster_C2", "rcep_C1")]
mytimes <- seq(300, 3e5, len = 100)
set.seed(59281)

my_sobol <- ODEsobol(mod = myODEmod, pars = parnames,
                     state_init = myinit,
                     times = mytimes,
                     n = 500,
                     rfuncs = "runif",
                     rargs = paste0("min = ", mylower, ", max = ", myupper),
                     sobol_method = "Martinez",
                     ode_method = "lsoda",
                     parallel_eval = TRUE,
                     parallel_eval_ncores = 2)
```

While my similar simple toy model with only two chemical species works, running this version results in the following error:

```
Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
  2 nodes produced errors; first error: subscript out of bounds
```

Does anyone know what might be wrong? I noticed that 'subscript out of bounds' often comes from referencing an index that isn't present in an object. Hence I've compared the lengths of all my vectors and I am pretty sure there are no constants in the model that are missing from my parameters. I re-ordered the parameters in different ways just in case they needed to be in the same order that they appear in the function. Thanks in advance.